# How do I find all "last names" which are shared by 5-10 users in an /etc/passwd file?

Tags: regex, perl, match, etcpasswd

So far I have this code:

```
#!/use/bin/perl -w

$filename = '/etc/passwd';

open(FILE, $filename) or die "Could not read from $filename, program halting.";
while (<FILE>) {
    chomp;
    ($username, $password, $uid, $gid, $uname, $home, $shell) = split(':', $_);
    my ($lastname, $firstname) = split(/ /, $uname, 2);
}

close FILE;
```

But now I am stuck with what to do next. My rational at the time was to split up the 7 values on the /etc/passwd file at do a match to see how many $lastnames had 5-10 matches, but then I would not know what the associated $username is with them.

For my final output I need to have a list of last names which are shared by 5-10 people so sample output would be something like:

smith : john samantha jared57 dragonx349 6tron39

Comment: Hint: use a hash with the last name as the key and a list of userids as the value.  For each last name, look it up in the hash and add the userid to the list.

Comment: ^ last name as the key and a reference to an array of userids as the value

Comment: I'm not good with perl, but here is a `sed` line in case it helps: `sed -n 's/^[^ :]* \([^:]*\).*/\1/p' /etc/passwd | sort | uniq -c | sed -n '/^ *[0-9]\{2,\}/{s/.* \(.*\)$/\1/;H};${x;y/\n/ /;s/^ //;p}'`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#always use strict. use warnings
use strict; 
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $filename = '/etc/passwd';

#use lexical file handle, don't need to explicitly close
#3 argument form of open.   `use autodie;` takes care of error checking.
open my $fh, '<', $filename;

#users will hold key value pairs. Key = lastname, Values: arrayref of usernames
my %users; 

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($username, $uname) = (split ':')[0, 4]; #Got rid of other data, not using it
    my $lastname = (split ' ', $uname)[0]; #Only need the lastname
    push @{ $users{$lastname} }, $username;
}

#Get keys of lastnames that are shared by 5 or more people
my @five_plus = grep { @{ $users{$_} } >= 5 } keys %users;

#So you can see the data
for my $key(@five_plus){
    print "$key:\n";
    print "\t$_\n" for(@{ $users{$key} });
}
```

Comment: at the line where you get the keys of lastnames how do you limit it so that it only goes up to 10?

so that it is at least 5 and at most 10. I've tried appending <=10 to it and it would not compile.

Comment: @user3735891 try replacing grep with `grep {my $t = @{ $users{$_} }; ($t >= 5 && $t <= 10)} keys %users;`